# Using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse not opening the page in correct format (the proper styling format)

Tags: apache

For example, if i write in my `httpd.conf`:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /fb http://localhost:2020/fb
ProxyPassReverse /fb http://localhost:2020/fb
ServerName localhost
```

Though on typing in url: `http:ip/fb` opens the page but its not in right format/styling.

Also whats the exact concept behind this might be I am missing something. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Most likely there is an issue with loading the style sheet definitions alongside the "page", so the markup definition. Note that the style sheets are typically loaded as separate files, so separate requests. I suggest you open your browsers development console, seleect the "Network" tab and examine the request done when you load the page. Anything odd? Any errors there?

Comment: No errors. Does the /fb in this line hold any significance or do we have to define somewhere anything for this?

Comment: Well, the `/fb` is part of the URL you want to proxy. I cannot say if that is correct, _you_ must know which URL you want to proxy. Every URL starting like that (`http://your-server.site/fb`) will be proxied to that internal server at port 2020, everything _not_ starting like that will _not_ be proxied.

Comment: One note about the `http://lcoalhost:2020/`... this will only work if ressource you are trying to access as backend server is located on the same system that host the http server where you implement this proxy rules on. That `lcoalhost` is resolved by the http _server_ in this case, _not_ by your client browser.

Comment: Ok being more clear, on my machine say tomcat is running on port 8080 and my app hosted on tomcat is say /app and we start the httpd.so it will be like:   ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app   , Now if i want to open the tomcat home page through this same ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, those are internals that I cannot really help with I guess. Your questions read a bit as if you did not check the documentation.... Don't get this wrong! But you _really_ should do so. Always. The documentations are a much more precise source of information than any help boards or examples on google out there: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: thanks for the source!!